# How to make the form inline using simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form using simple-form with bootstrap:

```
= simple_form_for(@course) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :class_size
    = f.simple_fields_for :lessons do |lesson|
      = render 'courses/partial/lesson_fields', f: lesson
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Lesson', f, :lessons,
          partial: 'courses/partial/lesson_fields', class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs"
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

**lesson_fields.html.haml**

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :date, as: :string, :input_html => { class: "datepicker" }
  = f.input :location
  = f.input :description
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove Lesson", f, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs"
```

How to make the lesson form in a single line?

Comment: which css library are you using? Bootstrap? Material design?

Comment: You can always [check the bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) for how to implement this.

Comment: @SunnyK my question is not about how to use bootstrap tags, but how to put the tags like `class="form-inline"` in the simple-form

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `:html` part?

```
= simple_form_for @object, html:{id:"<form_id>", class: "<you can define HTML classes here>"} do |f|
```

So here if you wanted to set the `form-inline` class along with `simple_form_for`, then you can set it inside the html part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
= simple_form_for(@course, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'form-inline' } }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-group
    = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  .form-group
    = f.input :class_size, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  .form-group
    = f.simple_fields_for :lessons do |lesson|
      = render 'courses/partial/lesson_fields', f: lesson
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Lesson', f, :lessons,
          partial: 'courses/partial/lesson_fields', class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs"
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

I hope this help you.